# ActiveRecord order nested items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have models Ticket and Service

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :medic
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services

  validates_presence_of :services
end

class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tickets
end
```

and Service model has field `code` and `name`.
So `services` table has records like

```
id |  code  | name 
1  |  5.1   | value 1
2  |  5.2   | value 2
3  |  6.1   | value 3
and so on
```

Is it possible to make query to get Tickets ordered by *name* including Services ordered by *code* (for example)?

```
Ticket.includes(:services, :medic)
        .order(date: :desc, created_at: :desc)
        .where(where_conditions)    (works fine, but without services order)
```

I did smth like this using Sequelize but don't know how it should be done using ActiveRecord. I've tried

```
Ticket.includes(:services, :medic)
        .order(date: :desc, created_at: :desc, "services.code": :desc)
        .distinct
        .where(where_conditions)
```

but got

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tickets.services.code: SELECT DISTINCT "tickets".* FROM "tickets" WHERE "tickets"."date" BETWEEN ? AND ? AND "tickets"."enabled" = ? ORDER BY "tickets"."date" DESC, "tickets"."created_at" DESC, "tickets"."services.code" DESC):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more 'api-using' solutions you can use Arel:

```rb
ticket = Ticket.arel_table
service = Service.arel_table

Ticket.includes(:services, :medic).references(:services)
      .order(ticket[:date].desc, ticket[:created_at].desc, service[:code].desc)
      .distinct
      .where(where_condition)
```

Or:

```rb
Ticket.includes(:services, :medic).references(:services)
      .order(Ticket.arel_table[:date].desc, Ticket.arel_table[:created_at].desc, Service.arel_table[:code].desc)
      .distinct
      .where(where_condition)
```

Comment: Alternatively you can leave out the `ticket` arel table and stack the `order` call instead. `.order(date: :desc, created_at: :desc).order(service[:code].desc)` or use a hash in a single `order` call `.order({ date: :desc, created_at: :desc }, service[:code].desc)`

Comment: Even better indeed

Answer (score 1):

You can pass exact `order` clause to into the ActiveRecord `order` method by string:

```
Ticket.includes(:services, :medic).references(:services)
      .order('tickets.date desc, tickets.created_at desc, services.code desc')
      .distinct
      .where(where_condition)
```

Note that I also added `references(:services)` to notify ActiveRecord that you want to put some condition or other clause on this table, otherwise ActiveRecord by default creates separate DB query, without `join`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Are there another more 'api-using' solutions?